# Running Android systrace on device

Tags: android, debugging, trace, systrace

I'm unable to run the Android SDK tool called systrace.pl because I get errors like:

```
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory
```

And indeed the /sys/kernel/debug/tracing directory doesn't even exist.

A little research showed I need to enable debugfs with the following command:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

Running mount there afterwards indicates the debugfs is running:

```
#mount
...
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
...
```

And I have trace enabled (all items) in the developer settings menu. I'm using the stock ROM 4.1.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S3.

There's a lot of articles out there on systrace for Android but nothing seems to solve the problem of no files actually being generated in /sys/kernel/debug/tracing...

Comment: Does `$ adb shell atrace --list-categories` work?

Comment: with my configuration works but from Eclipse I get same error

Comment: @dtmilano  atrace: unrecognized option `--list-categories'

Comment: '$adb shell atrace --help' ?

Comment: It's just a typo. The command is `$ adb shell atrace --list_categories`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html) document:

> Tracing on Android 4.3 and higher
>
> To run a trace on Android 4.3 and higher devices:
>
> ```
> Make sure the device is connected through a USB cable and is enabled for debugging.
> ```

I think that systrace must be run on a device, not an emulator. I'm getting the same error in my emulator.

Comment: Why would this not be allowed to run on an emulator?  I don't get it - what were the engineers thinking in creating this limitation...

Answer (score 1):

Answered the same question below:

[Make Systrace work with 4.1.2 device on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747616/make-systrace-work-with-4-1-2-device-on-mac/22676745#22676745)

Looks like your systrace is not enabled on the kernel your device is running, you need to replace your boot.img with one that has systrace support.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to that categories that you have selected.

use following command to check what all categories that current device can support.

```
$python systrace.py -l 

     gfx - Graphics
   input - Input
    view - View System
 webview - WebView
      wm - Window Manager
      am - Activity Manager
      sm - Sync Manager
   audio - Audio
   video - Video
  camera - Camera
     hal - Hardware Modules
     app - Application
     res - Resource Loading
  dalvik - Dalvik VM
      rs - RenderScript
  bionic - Bionic C Library
   power - Power Management
```

root and remount the device before running above command.

```
adb root
adb remount
```