# Unable to collect systrace in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, systrace

Unexpected error while collecting system trace

```
Details: Unexpected error while collecting system trace.
Unable to find trace start marker 'TRACE:':
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory (2)
error opening
```

Using windows 7 with python 2.7 and eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android DDMS v22.0.1 unable to generate a systrace using Droid Razor 4.1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223244/android-ddms-v22-0-1-unable-to-generate-a-systrace-using-droid-razor-4-1-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! - `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite` - this looks like a Linux path; you probably installed Linux-specific plugins in a Windows installation; remove them and install Windows-specific plugins.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Android, and the failing Linux path is on the attached device.  The OP doesn't actually say so though, so I'm hesitant to add the Android tag.

Comment: Hi user @user3879701, you should post follow-up questions as a separate question, possibly linking to the previous one in the question body. In this case however I think you should do a clean installation - you don'need to uninstall the current one, you can do it in parallel

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, the systrace.py tries to read/write the /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite file in the *connected device* not on the host machine. the error OP pasted is due to the lack of support for running systrace on the device. see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17223244/1523910) for more details.